# Linux: "authconfig --update" in SuSE?

Tags: linux, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux, opensuse, opensuse-12.2

What is the equivalent SuSE command for authconfig --update  redhat command
Suse 11.*

I could not  find any command online to try it
authconfig --update doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

You do this via Yast2.

For documentation see section "[4 Setting Up Authentication Servers and Clients Using YaST](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/42.2/security/html/book.security/cha.security.auth.html)".